# No column name was specified for column 4 of 'a'

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, sql-server-2016

```
select a.*, b.remark from 
(
    SELECT 
        [TypeSize] , 
        [ShapeCode] , 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dima <> 0 THEN 
                 'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
          END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimb <> 0 THEN 
                   ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimc <> 0 THEN 
                   ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimd <> 0 THEN 
                   ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dime <> 0 THEN 
                   ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimf <> 0 THEN 
                   ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimg <> 0 THEN 
                   ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimn <> 0 THEN 
                   ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END
          AS dimension,
          min(c.CreatedDtTm)
    FROM            bar_schedule_detail c
    WHERE           active = 1 
    AND             barid = @BarId    
    GROUP BY
        [TypeSize] , 
        [ShapeCode] , 
        CASE 
            WHEN dima <> 0 THEN 
                 'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
          END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimb <> 0 THEN 
                   ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimc <> 0 THEN 
                   ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimd <> 0 THEN 
                   ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dime <> 0 THEN 
                   ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimf <> 0 THEN 
                   ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimg <> 0 THEN 
                   ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimn <> 0 THEN 
                   ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END
) as a, bar_schedule_detail b
where a.typesize = b.typesize
and a.shapecode = b.shapecode
and 
(
   CASE 
     WHEN b.dima <> 0 THEN 
          'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
   END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimb <> 0 THEN 
            ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimc <> 0 THEN 
            ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimd <> 0 THEN 
            ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dime <> 0 THEN 
            ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimf <> 0 THEN 
            ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimg <> 0 THEN 
            ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimn <> 0 THEN 
            ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END
) = a.dimension
and a.CreatedDtTm = b.CreatedDtTm
and b.active = 1 
and b.barid = @BarId
```

When I execute this code, I get this error :

> No column name was specified for column 4 of 'a'.

Does anyone know what the problem? This section is where I encounter the error :

```
as a, bar_schedule_detail b
where a.typesize = b.typesize
and a.shapecode = b.shapecode
```

Comment: Try changing `min(c.CreatedDtTm)` to `min(c.CreatedDtTm) as columnName`

Comment: Execute correctly inside the sql sever, but when i debug it, the page cannot be displayed. It displays this error message 

at System.Data.DataTable.EnableConstraints() at System.Data.DataTable.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value) at System.Data.DataTable.EndLoadData() at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue from the one this post was about. You may ask a new question, but please accept one of the working answers to this one first.

Comment: That said, I don't know how you are using the calculated `dimension` field, but if `dima = 0` then that field will begin with a comma, which could cause you problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give alias name for all your sub query columns :

```
  SELECT ....., 
         .....,
         ....., MIN(c.CreatedDtTm) AS CreatedDT
```

In your sub query `SELECT` clause give alias name for min(c.CreatedDtTm) column

Comment: @Khalif,What alias name you given for CreatedDtTm in A subquery.Specify that alias name in a.Alias_name= b.CreatedDtTm

Comment: It has been solved and can execute in sql
I put MIN(c.CreatedDtTm) AS CreatedDT

Then CreatedDT = b.CreatedDtTm

Comment: Currently the problem now, is that it can execute in sql, but it cannot be displayed in crystal report. Not sure why. when i debug it. the page display error message at System.Data.DataTable.EnableConstraints() at System.Data.DataTable.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value) and more.

Comment: @Khalif,It's not under any database tag.you ask another question under tag .NET or any other specified tags.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the feedback